# Matching Strings In Array with an other Array from NsUserDefaults

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, tableview, cell

Array From Defaults

```
NSMutableArray* saveSelectedPlaces;

NSArray* titleArray = @[@"Akshardham",
                                @"Charminar",
                                @"Golden Temple",
                                @"Indian Gate",
                                @"Kedartnath Temple",
                                @"Ladakh",
                                @"Manasasarovar",
                                @"Mumbai",
                                @"Ooty",
                                @"Tajmahal",
                                @"Thar Desert",];
        Title = [titleArray mutableCopy];
```

My logic to compare strings

```
    for (NSString* currentString in saveSelectedPlaces) {
        if (detailcell.DetailTableCellTitle.text == currentString){
            detailcell.favouriteButton.selected = YES;
          [detailcell.favouriteButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"HeartSelectedSmall"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        }
    }
```

I have a array of titles saved in defaults , i want to compare those strings with an other array " Title . Then if it matches i want to highlight the images.

Simply, am trying to favoriting a cell.

Please, HELP ME 
Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

Replace `if (detailcell.DetailTableCellTitle.text == currentString)` with `if ([detailcell.DetailTableCellTitle.text isEqualToString: currentString])`

> The == is simply compares the pointers, which will usually be different even if their contents are the same. The isEqualToString method compares their contents.

More Simple way : You can check if an NSArray contains an object with `containsObject`.

```
BOOL contains = [saveSelectedPlaces containsObject: detailcell.DetailTableCellTitle.text];
if (contains)
{
 \\ add your code 
}
```

Comment: Can you please help me to show those selected items in an other tab? i have an other tab with table view, and i want to show all the saved items in an other tab ...any suggestions ?

Comment: use tableview methods to display data using user selected items count.

Comment: can elaborate a bit more? and my new class is in swift while this is in objective c